# Is there anyway i can use StreamTableEnvrionment in ProcessWindowFunction?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, apache-hudi

**Scenario**

Using Flink to read MySQL binlog and write to a Hudi table, but I want to partition the binlog data source into windows, and batch insert all the data within a window into the Hudi table when the window closes.
My current approach is to use a `ProcessWindowFunction` to process all the data within one window, concatenate all data of each window into an SQL statement, and perform the batch insertion when the window ends by using the `executeSql()` method of `StreamTableEnvironment`.

**Problem**

It seems `StreamTableEnvironment` can not be used in `ProcessWindowFunction`

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the StreamExecutionEnvironment is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2052)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.WindowedStream.process(WindowedStream.java:602)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.WindowedStream.process(WindowedStream.java:584)
    at flink_learn.chapter09_flinkcdc.Test03_MySqlToHudi.main(Test03_MySqlToHudi.java:113)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:624)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:143)
    ... 7 more
```

**Thought**

I used to think that use RichSinkFunction() to implement what i want, but it seems like Hudi doesn't have any flink api for bulk insert, so the only way i can bulk insert data into hudi table is using the executeSql() method of StreamTableEnvironment.

**Code**

```java
public class Test05_MySqlToHudi {
    
    private static String HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private static String USERNAME = "root";
    private static String PASSWORD = "root";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setString(RestOptions.BIND_PORT, "8881");

        StreamExecutionEnvironment sEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(configuration);
        StreamTableEnvironment sTableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(sEnv);

        sEnv.setParallelism(1);
        sEnv.enableCheckpointing(3000);

        String createDeptTableSql = "create table dept(\n" +
                "  dept_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT ENFORCED,\n" +
                "  dept_name varchar(10)\n" +
                ")\n" +
                "with (\n" +
                "  'connector' = 'hudi',\n" +
                "  'path' = 'hdfs://localhost:9000/hudi/dept',\n" +
                "  'table.type' = 'MERGE_ON_READ'\n" +
                ")";
        sTableEnv.executeSql(createDeptTableSql);

        String createStaffTableSql = "create table staff(\n" +
                "  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT ENFORCED,\n" +
                "  username varchar(10),\n" +
                "  password varchar(10),\n" +
                "  phone varchar(10),\n" +
                "  role_id bigint,\n" +
                "  dept_id bigint\n" +
                ")\n" +
                "with (\n" +
                "  'connector' = 'hudi',\n" +
                "  'path' = 'hdfs://localhost:9000/hudi/staff',\n" +
                "  'table.type' = 'MERGE_ON_READ'\n" +
                ")";
        sTableEnv.executeSql(createStaffTableSql);

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> process = sEnv
                .fromSource(getMySqlStreamSource(), WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "MySQL Source")
                .map(new JsonToEntityMapFunction())
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<JSONObject>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                        .withTimestampAssigner((SerializableTimestampAssigner<JSONObject>) (binlogJson, recordTimestamp) -> {

                            String arriveTime = JSONObject.parseObject(binlogJson.getString("after")).getString("arrive_time");
                            String arriveTimeUTC = arriveTime.replace("Z", " UTC");
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
                            Date date = null;
                            try {
                                date = sdf.parse(arriveTimeUTC);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                            return date.getTime();
                        }))
                .keyBy(binlogJson -> JSONObject.parseObject(binlogJson.getString("source")).getString("table"))
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<JSONObject, String, String, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(String key, ProcessWindowFunction<JSONObject, String, String, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<JSONObject> elements, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

                        if ("dept".equals(key)) {
                            String insertDataSql = "insert into dept values\n";
                            ArrayList<JSONObject> deptJsonObjects = Lists.newArrayList(elements);
                            for (JSONObject jsonObject : deptJsonObjects) {
                                String afterData = jsonObject.getString("after");
                                JSONObject rowDataObject = JSON.parseObject(afterData);
                                Long deptId = Long.parseLong(rowDataObject.getString("dept_id"));
                                String deptName = rowDataObject.getString("dept_name");
                                System.out.println("dept---> " + deptId + " -----  " + deptName);
                                insertDataSql += "(" + deptId + ",'" + deptName + "'),\n";
                            }
                            insertDataSql = insertDataSql.substring(0, insertDataSql.length() - 2);
                            // out.collect(insertDataSql);
                            sTableEnv.executeSql(insertDataSql);  // report exception

                        } else {
                            String insertDataSql = "insert into staff values\n";
                            ArrayList<JSONObject> staffJsonObjects = Lists.newArrayList(elements);
                            for (JSONObject jsonObject : staffJsonObjects) {
                                String afterData = jsonObject.getString("after");
                                JSONObject rowDataObject = JSON.parseObject(afterData);
                                Long id = Long.parseLong(rowDataObject.getString("id"));
                                String username = rowDataObject.getString("username");
                                String phone = rowDataObject.getString("phone");
                                String password = rowDataObject.getString("password");
                                Long deptId = Long.parseLong(rowDataObject.getString("dept_id"));
                                Long roleId = Long.parseLong(rowDataObject.getString("role_id"));
                                insertDataSql += "(" + id + ",'" + username + "','" + password + "','" + phone + "'," + deptId + "," + roleId + "),\n";
                            }
                            insertDataSql = insertDataSql.substring(0, insertDataSql.length() - 2);
                            sTableEnv.executeSql(insertDataSql); // report exception
                            // out.collect(insertDataSql);
                        }
                    }
                });
        

        sEnv.execute("mysql to hudi");
    }
}
```